# red dot and green outline of a box appered on screen – Mint Cinnamon

Tags: xorg, window

While experimenting with scrcpy this red dot and green rectangle appeared.
I had my phone lean against the screen on that area, thus I only notices it later.

[image]
[image]

This abnormality is only affecting the Xorg server. On a different Xorg server or tty this abnormality is not present.

Also on the lock-screen it is present.

[image]

It seems to have no "hithox". Clicking on it will lead to clicking on the window behind it.

I expect it to go away on a restart, but I typically never restart my computer unless absolutely necessary and I am much more interested in diagnosing the issue and finding the cause than just getting rid of the issue.

What I've already tried, is:

- using pkill to kill scrcpy if it somehow was running in the background. It wasn't and it had no effect
- running xkill and clicking on the abnormality. The window that is behind it will get closed
- doing the same things I did before on a different Xorg server under a different user. I wasn't able to reproduce it.

I am using Linux Mint and Cinnamon.

Any ideas what I should try out?

Comment: Pressing Alt+F2, entering `r` in the window that appears and pressing enter will restart your cinnamon session without restarting the machine or logging you out. That will probably remove it. It won't help you learn what it was (but it is probably just a random bug that you won't easily find) but at least it will fix without rebooting.

Comment: this is an equivalent to executing `cinnamon --replace`, right?

Answer (score 0):

It disappeared when I had to restart Firefox, because of an update. Now that it's gone I'll close this question.